# Image event on size loaded

Tags: javascript, metadata, dom-events, image-size

As you can see when a webpage loads a big image, browser can know image sizes (width and height) at the beginning of loading.

I'm looking for a way in Javascript to add event called when sizes is known (not when full image is loaded) ; a bit like `metadataloaded` for video.

Code example:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'images/picture.jpg';

console.log(img.width,img.height);  // 0, 0 (image size is not known yet)

img.addEventListener('imagesizeloaded', () => {
    console.log(img.width,img.height);  //expected: 1024, 768 (for example)
});
```

Comment: I think `load` is the only option

Comment: you could send the metadata through other means

Comment: I don't think such an event (image header loaded) exists

Answer (score 4):

You could create an AJAX callback on the server to fetch the metadata. Better yet, send the metadata with the file name.

Example (client) using jQuery:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "images/picture.jpg";

$.get("ajax.php", {action: "getImageSize", url: img.src})
 .success(function(r){
   console.log(r.width, r.height)
 })
```

The server part will depend on what server-side technology you are using. It needs to

```
open the image by its url
read the image metadata
send a JSON response
```

---

At worst, you could poll the image data until it's non-zero.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "images/picture.jpg";

(function testImageSizeKnown(){
  if(img.height && img.width){
    console.log(img.height, imp.width)
  }else{
    setTimeout(testImageSizeKnown, 100) // check every 100 ms
  }
)()
```

Comment: Thank ! I target a non server dependent solution, then 2nd version is better for me, but is it possible to use listener a "onprogress"  event (on image or on xhr2 sending data to new image when load ending) instead of use a timeout?

Comment: @Yukulélé The image element doesn't seeem to have a `progress` event that you could use according to MDN - and fetching the image data via XHR seems problematic (and you'd still probably have to be able to parse the partial binary data, as well as finally display the image). You can attach the `onprogress` handler to the image but I doubt it will be called.